# preg_match_all get the right "end Tag"

Tags: php, regex, tags, preg-match-all

I have a little BBCode System which is working with preg_match_all to parse my Tags.
Now my Problem is when i have sth. like

```
[tab]

[tab_item id='tab' title='Titel']
Test Content
[/tab_item]

[tab_item id='tab2' title='Titel 2']
Test Content 2
[/tab_item]

[/tab]
```

i get the next closing tab. In this Case i get for [tab] the closing tab [/tab_item] and not the same named tag [/tab].

This is how my Code looks like:

```
    $pattern = "/\[(.*?) (.*?)](.*?)\[\/(.*?)\]/msi";
    preg_match_all($pattern, $article->text, $matches);

    $quotes = array();

    foreach($matches[2] as $id => $match)
    {

        preg_match_all('/(\w*?)=\'(.*?)\'/msi', $match, $attr_matches);

        echo $matches[1][$id]; //the first Tag [tab]
        echo $matches[4][$id]; //wrong closing Tag [/tab_item]


        $quote = array(
            'type'          =>  trim($matches[1][$id]),
            'text'          =>  trim($matches[3][$id]),
            'attr'    =>  array_combine($attr_matches[1], $attr_matches[2])
            );

        echo '<pre>'.print_r($quote,1).'</pre>';
    }
```

Now my Question is, is it possible to have a kind of variable in the first preg_match_all which says that these to Tags must be the same ?

Comment: what is the expected output

Comment: i want to get to whole content between the [tab] and [/tab] Tag so i can preg_match_all that content again to filter the tab Items out...

Comment: There are already plenty of BBCode libraries for PHP, is there any particular reason why you don't just use one of those?

Comment: it is just for learning and understanding the preg_match_all mechanism

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\[(.*?)\]((?:(?!\[\/\1\])[\s\S])*)\[\/\1\]
```

You can use something like this to get data between `[tab]` and `[/tab]`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/eS7gD7/12

Comment: thanks wokring fine! :) i took a diffrent pattern which can also read attributes in the main Tag. Will post this later as answer

Answer (score 0):

I use a different pattern than vks, but i think both are fine.

```
/\\[(.*?) (.*?)](.*?)\\[\\/\\1\\]/msi
```

The main different is, that i can also read Tags which do not have "subTags" like [blockqoute][/blockqoute], and i can read attributes from the main tag too.

But this was not exactly what i ask for, but that what i wanted at all.